React Router Form actions
I would like to ask question. I have vanilla React app, using createBrowserRouter from React-Router-DOM. I would like to use action to send data to a server. I have a form component where I have want to get all informations. So I am using input with names so I can use the in action function via formData. But I ran into a problem. Inside of my FormComponent I have a state called items. In my Form I have a div where I map over items to create div with 3 inputs. One each for name, quantity, and price. So far ok, I keep track of all the changes, but then when I want to submit my local items, I don't know how.
const FormComponent = () => 
  const [items, setItems] = useState<Item[]>([
    { name: '', quantity: 1, price: 0 },
  ])

  const handleItemChange = (
    index: number,
    field: keyof Item,
    value: Item[keyof Item]
  ) => {
    const newItems: any[] = [...items];
    // assign the new value
    newItems[index][field] = value;

    setItems(newItems);
  };

  const addItem = () => {
    setItems([...items, { name: '', quantity: 1, price: 0 }]);
  };

  return (
    <Form method="post">
      .....
      <div>
        <h3>Items</h3>
        {items.map((item, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <label>
              Name:
              <input
                type='text'
                value={item.name}
                onChange={(e) =>
                  handleItemChange(index, 'name', e.target.value)
                }
                required
              />
            </label>
            <label>
              Quantity:
              <input
                type='number'
                value={item.quantity}
                onChange={(e) =>
                  handleItemChange(index, 'quantity', Number(e.target.value))
                }
                required
              />
            </label>
            <label>
              Price:
              <input
                type='number'
                value={item.price}
                onChange={(e) =>
                  handleItemChange(index, 'price', Number(e.target.value))
                }
                required
              />
            </label>
          </div>
        ))}
        <button type='button' onClick={addItem}>
          Add Item
        </button>
      </div>
      ....
    </Form>
  )
}

So my question is, how can I pass data from my local state to the action?
I tried already using the onSubmit way on my form, but then I don't see the data in action.
I have Login and Register page, where everything works, but they are simple components so it was easy to implement the action.
I've been lost for a while now.

Give your form field inputs a name attribute/prop so they are identifiable in the form data. For arrays of field data you'll want to uniquely identify each element within the form data.
Example implementation:
{items.map((item, index) => (
  <div key={index}>
    <label>
      Name:
      <input
        name={`name-${index}`} // <--
        type="text"
        value={item.name}
        onChange={(e) =>
          handleItemChange(index, "name", e.target.value)
        }
        required
      />
    </label>
    <label>
      Quantity:
      <input
        name={`quantity-${index}`} // <--
        type="number"
        value={item.quantity}
        onChange={(e) =>
          handleItemChange(index, "quantity", Number(e.target.value))
        }
        required
      />
    </label>
    <label>
      Price:
      <input
        name={`price-${index}`} // <--
        type="number"
        value={item.price}
        onChange={(e) =>
          handleItemChange(index, "price", Number(e.target.value))
        }
        required
      />
    </label>
  </div>
))}

When the form is submitted you can access the form data:
{
  action: async ({ request }) => {
    const data = await request.formData();

    for (const value of data.entries()) {
      console.log(value);
    }

    return ....;
  },
  path: "/....",
  element: <FormComponent />,
},


